# Another loop iteration of list

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, python-3.1

How to write this code correctly?

```
highScore=open('scores.txt',mode='r')
score=[]
i=0
print("\nName\t\tScore")
line=highScore.readline().strip('\n')
while line!="":
    line=str(line).split(', ')
    x=[line[0],int(line[1])]
    score.append(x)
    line=highScore.readline()
z=sorted(score, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=False)
for i in z:
    print(str(z[i][0])+"\t\t"+str(z[i][1]))
    i+=1
```

Expected to show name with tab with score of the same entry.

But error shown :

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: please add `z` to question !

Comment: you should be using str.format, it is a lot more readable than  `print(str(z[i][0])+"\t\t"+str(z[i][1]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `i` is not the index, it is each element out of your list. See the below example

```
z = 'abcde'
for i in z:
    print i

a
b
c
d
e
```

So you would want to change your code to

```
for i in z:
    print(str(i[0])+"\t\t"+str(i[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

i think `z` is a 2D array so replace this line :

```
for i in z:
    print(str(z[i][0])+"\t\t"+str(z[i][1]))
    i+=1
```

with this :

```
for i in z:
    print(str(i[0])+"\t\t"+str(i[1]))
```

Comment: well so try this answer and give me the result thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Just use `str.format` and access the subelements by index:

```
In [10]: z = [[1,2],[3,4]]


In [11]: for i in z:
   ....:     print("{}        {}".format(i[0],i[1]))
   ....:     
1       2
3       4
```

You are iterating over the element in `z` so just access each subelement by the index.

Comment: @LbertHartanto, forgot you were using python 3 you need parens for printing

Answer (score 0):

The line `line=highScore.readline().strip('\n')` is probably not what your trying to do. I think you want to read the entire file and break by new lines. So replace readline with read.

```
lines = highScore.read().strip('\n')
```

Then instead of a while loop you can use a for loop

```
for line in lines:
    for items in line.split(', '):
         score.append(list(items[0], items[1:]))
```